# Problems with Google Maps API asynchronous loading. Causes events to run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, asynchronous

I have tried to solve this issue for weeks, kinda ignored it lately, but it is really starting to annoy me. If someone could tell me what's wrong with my code, i would appreciate it.

Everything works, except that it makes my code run twice, and when i dynamically load my ajax content, it makes my code run even more times.

I am fairly sure it is because of the callback when asynchronous loading the google maps.

```
    if (window.google && google.maps) {
        initialize();
    } else {
        if (!$('script[src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_in=true&language=en&callback=initialize"]').length > 0) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_in=true&language=en&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
```

This is how i load the map. It works if you refresh the site, it jumps to the Else then. If i move around my site, which is loaded dynamic with Ajax, it goes into the IF, and run initialize().

Now... a simple console.log('test'); always fires twice, no matter what. And if i move away from the site, and go back, it fires three times, and if i go away and back one more time... you guessed it, four times test is written in console.

Now, is this where my problem is? Or does it look normal, and i should start looking at the script that loads my content with ajax?

This is my initialize function.

```
function initialize() {

    var cell;

    $('.integrator-country').text(localStorage.country);

    $("#select-country").children("option[value='" + localStorage.country + "']").prop('selected', true);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.latitude, localStorage.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: latlng
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        map.setCenter(latlng);
    });

    getIntegrators(localStorage.country, cell);
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `if (!$('script ...)` check as well as checking for `window.google.maps`?  I suspect it's loading the map script multiple times

Comment: Yes, i need it, otherwise the map wont load my settings. I will update my question with the initialize function.

Comment: if you get multiple console.logs check how often the script shows up in your source. maybe your if statement isnt working correct and you keep appending the script multiple times, so you get multiple callbacks

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent is being added everytime i switch to the page. Not sure if that tells anything... Other than that, i cant really see anything changing...

Comment: It is not only the google map events that fire multiple times. I have a drag and drop event, which adds a text to a div, and it will also multiply, and add more and more of the same text to that div, the more i go back and forth to the page. Maybe that information is relevant.

Comment: You sure you aren't calling initialize somewhere else?  Maybe in body on load?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.